# How to remove a specific marker from google maps in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am Vaibhav Pathak. I am working on a Flutter app in which I add markers in-app based on data change in firestore database and I want to remove the previous marker from the map using its marker id but I don't understand how to do it. I had watched many Youtube videos and blogs but I don't get to know this because of API changes in google maps flutter plugin. For your kind information, I want to tell that I am using the latest version of the google_maps flutter plugin.

My Code for Making Markers :

```
showLiveLocation(LatLng latLng) {
_markers.add(
  Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId(latLng.toString()),
    position: latLng,
    draggable: false,
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: "Live Order Location",
        snippet: "Dear customer your order is live at this place."),
    icon: liveLocation,
    visible: true,
  ),
);
```

}

Thanks for everyone's help.

github : [github@vkpdeveloper](https://github.com/vkpdeveloper)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to find that specific marker in your _markers list (e.g. by firstWhere()) and then remove it from the list of markers.

Edit:

```
Marker marker = _markers.firstWhere((marker) => marker.markerId.value == "myId",orElse: () => null);
setState(() {
   _markers.remove(marker); 
});
```

This will trigger a rebuild of your map where the marker is no longer included.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Thomas, my solution was:

```
setState(() {
  _markers.removeWhere((key, marker) => marker.markerId.value == "myMarkerId");
});
```